Hardhat error TS6046: Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2020', 'esnext'
Im having a problem with a repository. Whenever i try and run any hardhat command i get the below error.
user@users-MacBook-Pro internal-repo % node --version
v16.20.2
user@users-MacBook-Pro internal-repo % npm --version
8.19.4
user@users-MacBook-Pro internal-repo % npx --version
8.19.4
user@users-MacBook-Pro internal-repo % npx hardhat compile
An unexpected error occurred:

error TS6046: Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2020', 'esnext'.


Check the value of type field in your package.json.
Usually, it should be either:

module: when you’re importing the dependencies using import statements.
commonjs: when you’re importing the dependencies using require statements.


So its not possible to use both import and require?

Yes, not possible in a single project.
